# Outlook Addin - Attach image in body from resource

Tags: visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am currently developing an Outlook add in that automatically creates a signature in the body of a new email.

Currently it adds our company logo from a network share via HTML.

```
bodyTest.AppendLine(@"<tr><td ><img src='\\netshare\branding\logo.jpg'/></td></tr></table>");
```

But if the user is on a laptop working from home then the network share doesnt exist. How can I insert an image from an application resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never use an absolute path in a specific file system unless when testing. I didn't use visual studio before but in eclipse for example you can put the image in the program resources so when you compile/deploy the program its gonna be always there within the app. You should create a folder like img/ inside your project folder and give the path to that.